# why when click on edit it is not showing the model of clicked data in a select list as i want to show the model?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, laravel

this is my controller function

```
public function getModel($make_id = null)
{
    $make_id = request()->make_id;
    $carsmodel = CarModel::where('make_id', $make_id)->orderBy('model', 'ASC')->get();
    return response()->json(['carsmodel' => $carsmodel]);
}
```

this my js

```
getModel: function (url,make_id) {
    m=null;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: { make_id: make_id,},
        success: function (response) {
           $("#model_id").empty();
           $("#model_id").append('<option value="">Choose</option>');
           $.each(response.carsmodel, function (index, carModel) {
               $("#model_id").append(
                   '<option value="' +carModel.id + '">' + carModel.model + "</option>"
               );
           });
        },
    });
    return m;
},
```

this is how it is implementing

```
 $("#make_id").on('change', function() {
        var make_id = $(this).val();
        var url = '{{ route("cars.submodels.getModel")}}';
        App.Cars.getModel(url, make_id);
    });
```

this is the function that is loading when user clicked on edit button

```
App.Cars.SubModels = {
        loadEditData(e) {
            var $url = $(e).attr('href');
            var url = '/admin/cars/submodels/getModel';
            $.get($url, function($response) {
                //console.log($response.model.model)
                $('#createEditForm').trigger('reset')
                $('#createEditModal').modal('show')
                $('#make_id').val($response.resp.make_id)
                //App.Cars.getModel(url, $response.resp.make_id);
                $('#sub_model').val($response.resp.sub_model)
                $('#sub_model_ar').val($response.resp.sub_model_ar)
                $('#year_from').val($response.resp.year_from)
                $('#year_to').val($response.resp.year_to)
                $('#car_source').val($response.resp.car_source)
                $('#method').val("PUT");
                $('#sub_model_image').removeAttr('required');
                $('#url').val($response.route);
                $('#create').html("Update");
                $("form#createEditForm input").removeClass("error");
                $("form#createEditForm input").parent().find("label.error").remove();
                $(".close").on("click", function() {
                    $("#createEditModal").modal('hide');
                });
                $("#close-btn").on("click", function() {
                    $("#createEditModal").modal('hide');
                });
                App.Cars.getModel(url, $response.resp.make_id, function(response) {
                    $('#model_id').empty().append('<option value="">Choose</option>');
                    $.each(response.carsmodel, function(index, carModel) {
                        $("#model_id").append(
                            '<option value="' + carModel.id + '">' + carModel.model + "</option>"
                        );
                    });
                    $('#model_id').val($response.resp.model_id);
                });

            })
        },
    }
```

so when user is clicking on edit button all that data is already filled but model is not filling automatically here i call the function too but still it is not filling the model everything is running fine except that please tell me what to do.

Comment: you should ensure that the getModel function is returning the expected data when called within the loadEditData function. You can add some console.log statements to debug and see if the response data contains the necessary model information.
$.get($url, function($response) {
    console.log($response); // Check the response data
    // ... rest of the code
});

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be sure that the App.Cars.getModel function is being called after the edit modal is displayed and the make_id is set. I can see that In your code, you are calling App.Cars.getModel with a callback function, which probably is not necessary. Maybe you should try simplifying it:

Like that:

```js
$('#createEditModal').modal('show');
$('#make_id').val($response.resp.make_id);
    
// Call App.Cars.getModel directly
App.Cars.getModel(url, $response.resp.make_id);
    
// ... rest of the code
```

Other thing, did you open your browser's developer console and had check for any JavaScript errors? Some errors in other parts of your JavaScript code may interfere with the execution of the code that populates the model select list.

And you can also check your server-side code function in your controller (getModel). See if it is correctly retrieving and returning the model data based on the provided make_id.

Comment: yep there was nothing in console and data was retrieving correct sending ajax request to the controller again solved my problem